# Extract text between two nested elements using `BeautifulSoup`

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some htmls like below. How can I extract all text between `content` and `time`? The tag after `content` may not be `time` exactly. It could be some thing like `location`.

```
...
<p><strong> name：</strong></p>
<p> sdfsdf </p>
<p><strong> content：</strong></p>
<p> yangben</p>
<p> dsfs </p>
<p> dfsds </p>
<p> sdfs </p>
<p><strong> time：</strong></p>
<p> 2020-10-10</p>
<p><strong> ll：</strong></p>
<p> 2020-10-10</p>
...
```

Comment: Please also provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<p><strong> name:：</strong></p>
<p> sdfsdf </p>
<p><strong> content: </strong></p>
<p> yangben</p>
<p> dsfs </p>
<p> dfsds </p>
<p> sdfs </p>
<p><strong> time: </strong></p>
<p> 2020-10-10</p>
<p><strong> ll：</strong></p>
<p> 2020-10-10</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

content_start = soup.select_one("p:has(strong:-soup-contains(content))")
all_tags = []
for tag in content_start.find_next_siblings():
    prev_strong = tag.find_previous("strong")
    if prev_strong and "content" in prev_strong.text and not tag.strong:
        all_tags.append(tag)

print(all_tags)
```

Prints:

```
[<p> yangben</p>, <p> dsfs </p>, <p> dfsds </p>, <p> sdfs </p>]
```